# If-else statement either all or none

Tags: c++

PS: Not a homework question

I have three strings: `string1`, `string2`, `string3`

Either all of them have to be empty or none of them. In the invalid scenario where some of them (not all) are empty, I have to inform which one(s) is/are empty.

Following is my if-else block which is verbose. Is there a concise and better way to write the if-else block?

```
if(!string1.empty() || !string2.empty() || !string3.empty()) // Check if any one of them is non-empty
{
    // If any one of them is non-empty, all of them should be non-empty and I should inform which one(s) is/are empty
    bool some_string_is_empty = false;
    if(string1.empty())
    {
        some_string_is_empty = true;
        cout << "string1 is empty" << endl;
    }

    if(string2.empty())
    {
        some_string_is_empty = true;
        cout << "string2 is empty" << endl;
    }

    if(string3.empty())
    {
        some_string_is_empty = true;
        cout << "string3 is empty" << endl;
    }
    
    if(some_string_is_empty)
    {
        // This is an invalid state, return
        return 0;
    }
}

// We are now in a valid state 
{
    //do something
}
```

Comment: Maybe put the strings in an array and loop on that.

Comment: This problem statement makes no sense. If all string are empty, you cannot tell "the one that is empty".

Comment: @YvesDaoust: I read it as "when they're *not* either 'all empty' or 'all non-empty', I need to know which ones are empty." It's phrased awkwardly, but then, it's a kinda awkward problem to state.

Comment: @ShadowRanger: the question does not say if any single or all empty strings should be reported.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Edited for clarity

Comment: Your fix isn't any better. What is the meaning of "which one" when there are two empty strings ? And your implementation contradicts the rule "(not all)", as it will report all empty strings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can generically check for `n` booleans to be in agreement by simply adding them:

```
if ((Check1() + Check2() + ... + Checkn()) % n)
{
    // They're not all equal
}
```

Which we could make into a function like so:

```
template <class ... bools>
bool AllOrNothing (bools ... bs)
{
    return (0 + ... + bs) % sizeof...(bs);
}
```

In our case we can solve directly like this:

```
bool not_all_same = (string1.empty() + string2.empty() + string3.empty()) % 3;
```

https://godbolt.org/z/TK11rcxn3

Comment: You have assumed that there are two valid states: all none empty or all empty. In fact only all none empty is expected to be valid.

Comment: @MarekR, not an assumption. It's clearly stated in the OP `I have three strings: string1, string2, string3. Either all of them have to be empty or none of them. In the invalid scenario where some of them (not all) are empty, I have to inform which one(s) is/are empty.`

Comment: Ok you are right I'm wrong (and others too).

Comment: Don't do this for 2^31 bools ... (signed overflow)

Answer (score 4):

You can give names to your conditions:

```
bool e1 = string1.empty();
bool e2 = string2.empty();
bool e3 = string3.empty();
bool some_string_is_empty = e1 || e2 || e3;

if (some_string_is_empty)
    std::cout << "some string is empty\n";
if (e1)
    std::cout << "string1 is empty\n";
if (e2)
    std::cout << "string2 is empty\n";
if (e3)
    std::cout << "string3 is empty\n";
```

---

To answer the updated version of the question in the spirit of the above, if you have confusing/tricky logic, you can give meaningful names to intermediate results. Then it will be obvious whether your code is correct.

```
bool e1 = string1.empty();
bool e2 = string2.empty();
bool e3 = string3.empty();
bool some_string_is_empty = e1 || e2 || e3;
bool all_are_non_empty = !some_string_is_empty;
bool all_are_empty = e1 && e2 && e3;
bool is_valid_use_case = all_are_empty || all_are_non_empty;

if (!is_valid_use_case)
{
    std::cout << "Bad use case!\n";
    if (e1)
        ...
    if (e2)
        ...
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can loop over the strings, manually maintaining the number, replacing:

```
if(string1.empty())
{
    some_string_is_empty = true;
    cout << "string1 is empty" << endl;
}

if(string2.empty())
{
    some_string_is_empty = true;
    cout << "string2 is empty" << endl;
}

if(string3.empty())
{
    some_string_is_empty = true;
    cout << "string3 is empty" << endl;
}
```

with:

```
int i = 0;
for (const auto& s : {string1, string2, string3}) {
  ++i;
  if (s.empty()) {
    some_string_is_empty = true;
    cout << "string" << i << " is empty" << endl;
  }
}
```

That said, in practice, it usually makes sense to just have an array of the three strings in the first place, rather than numbered variable names.

Answer (score 1):

Extracting small functions is always best choice.

```cpp
bool testString(const std::string& s, std::string_view name)
{
   if (!s.empty()) return true;
   std::cout << name << " is empty.\n";
   return false;
}

void foo(const std::string& a, const std::string& b, const std::string& c)
{
    // single "&" is not a typo!
    if ((a.empty() && b.empty() && c.empty())
        || (testString(a, "a") & testString(b, "b") & testString(c, "c"))) {
       std::cout << "all strings are fine (all empty xor all none empty)\n";
    }
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/94Ko96cnn

Comment: Shouldn't `foo("", "", "")` print nothing? Only invalid string states cause print, if I'm reading the OP correctly.

Comment: he want to do some action in case everything is fine `// We are now in a valid state`, so I've added some extra print to show that it is actually run when needed.

Comment: hmmm. but shouldn't that `foo` be correct? why does your first `foo` print `all strings are fine`, but not your last? that implies to me that it's not correct.

Comment: OP wrote: `if(some_string_is_empty) { return 0; }` then he runs something under `// We are now in a valid state`

Answer (score 1):

You can add the name of non empty strings to a vector and check the size:

```
std::vector v;
v.reserve(3);
if (string1.empty()) v.push_back("string1");
if (string2.empty()) v.push_back("string2");
if (string3.empty()) v.push_back("string3");
if (v.size() != 0 && v.size() != 3)
    for (const auto &name : v)
       std::cout << name << " is empty\n";
```